# Удаленная работа Java сервера

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, сервер, хостинг

Всем привет.

Я пока начинающий java разработчик, однако есть некоторые наработки.

Возник такой вопрос: есть Java сервер и клиент (что-от вроде чата), тестировал у себя на компе, теперь хотелось бы реализовать его удаленную работу, то есть запустить его на хостинге с выделенным ip.

Как такое реализовать? Ни разу с таким не сталкивался, кто знает, можете помочь в данном вопросе?

Comment: @iandryxa5, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужен не хостинг (в том понимании, в котором он используется в php-мире), а полноценный сервер, на котором вы можете запускать процессы. Можете обратить взор на какой-нибудь [бюджетный VDS](http://lowendbox.com/) (10 долларов на месяцок экспериментов насобираете?) или облачный [бесплатный micro-instance от Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/free/) (их AFAIK дают на год бесплатно, при регистрации банковской карточки, сойдет виртуальная карта Qiwi, с парой долларов в рублевом эквиваленте).

В общем, регаете VDS, вам дают доступ к web-админке, как правило. Там вы настраиваете, тыкая в окошки, как правило, вид линукса, который вам нужен, внешний IP адрес (как минимум один вам дадут) и параметры подключения по SSH. Заливаете ваше серверное приложение по SFTP, логинитесь в SSH, запускаете приложение как обычно из командной строки (`java -jar blablabla.jar`).

Само собой может потребоваться установить java, хотя OpenJDK, вполне возможно, что будет. И открыть порт на фаерволле (часто это можно сделать из web-админки).

Если вы раньше не работали с линуксом - самое время начать.

---

Минутка патриотизма: на хабре писали про такой вот поисковик VDS-ок по требуемым параметрам - http://poiskvps.ru/.

Ну и баланса ради, заграница вам тоже поможет дешевыми VDS:

- http://lowendstock.com/
- http://serverbear.com/

Comment: спасибо за совет)

Answer (score -2):

openshift.com - условно бесплатный сервер

Comment: А можете поделиться ссылкой по данной теме, если не сложно?)